# Swift: How to cast value to Self in a class function

Tags: ios, swift

here I have a class function `public class func testing() -> Self`:

```
public extension UIViewController {
    public class func testing() -> Self {
        return getInstance()
    }
}
```

and a `getInstance() -> UIViewController` function which I can't be modified:

```
public func getInstance() -> UIViewController {
    return UIViewController()
}
```

now, how to cast the return value of `getInstance()` function to `Self` in `testing()` function?

```
return getInstance() // error
return getInstance() as! Self // error
return getInstance() as! UIViewController // error
```

Comment: `self` starts with a small letter.

Comment: @MartinR thx a lot

Answer (score 2):

Just change your function to

```
public extension UIViewController {
    public class func testing() -> UIViewController {
        return getInstance()
    }
}
```

The function needs to specify a return *Type* which in this case would always be UIViewController as thats the type you extend.

Comment: thx. But I want to return a `Self` type instead of `UIViewController` type, so I can get the right type by calling this function from subclasses.

Comment: Than you might be able to do it with Generics. if you are returning a type which is only determined at runtime then you have no way to cast another type to this unknown type. Generics would be the only way to do this that I know of